# Update SQL values with word + id column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database table, where I need to update column in rows

I need to update it with `Position` + id of row

Here is how I try to do this

```
UPDATE positions SET Name = 'Position'+Id WHERE Name IS NULL
```

But I get this error

> [22001][1292] Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Position'

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Though this does not look like a T-SQL error, thus is unlikely to be SQL Server.

Comment: Likely you need to cast `Id` to a varchar/char/nvarchar/string (pick a string type that matches `Name`)

Comment: @Larnu this is mysql

Comment: @EugeneSukh Please tag the RDBMS next time. I did it for you now. That will help get you an answer that actually works for you.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: The question is understandable. Don't see the need to add extra info @stickybit

Comment: @EugeneSukh: No it isn't. We don't know the types of the columns. We don't know if `'position'` really is meant to be a string literal or is a misquoted column name -- people do that, for whatever reason very often here. We don't know if `+` is meant to be string concatenation or arithmetic plus. All that would be clarified with a [example]. It might be understandable for you as you have all that information. We don't, we can only make educated guesses, but that's not how things should work here. But you have enough reputation to know that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a string.  The `+` operator is for addition.  The standard SQL operator for string concatenation is `||`.  So:

```
UPDATE positions
    SET Name = 'Position' || Id
    WHERE Name IS NULL;
```

Not all databases support this syntax.  Most either support `||` or the `CONCAT()` function:

```
UPDATE positions
    SET Name = CONCAT('Position', Id)
    WHERE Name IS NULL;
```

In general, both `||` and `CONCAT()` convert non-string values to strings.